# Javascript: Why is my total zero?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need a fresh pair of eyes on this simple bit of code, thank you.

```
var totalMessageCount = 0;
            $.get("/Messages/GetVendorMessageCount/", { vendorId: "@ViewBag.VendorId" })
                .done(function (data) {
                    totalMessageCount = totalMessageCount + Number(data);
                    $(".MessageCount").html(data);
                });
            $.get("/Messages/GetVendorNotifyCount/", { vendorId: "@ViewBag.VendorId" })
                .done(function (data) {
                    totalMessageCount = totalMessageCount + Number(data);
                    $(".NotifyCount").html(data);
                });
            $.get("/Messages/GetVendorTaskCount/", { vendorId: "@ViewBag.VendorId" })
                .done(function (data) {
                    totalMessageCount = totalMessageCount + Number(data);
                    $(".TaskCount").html(data);
                });
            console.log("-" + totalMessageCount);
            $(".TotalMessageCount").html(totalMessageCount);
```

My controller returns the correct int values for each .get and they are displaying correctly.  The problem is `totalMessageCount` is zero at the end.  So for some reason, the `totalMessageCount = totalMessageCount + Number(data)` line doesn't seem to be working. It's gotta be something stupid I'm doing, been a long day...  thanks

Comment: Because ajax is async. Your `$(".TotalMessageCount").html(totalMessageCount);` is executed before the controller methods return the values back to the client. Put that line of code in each `.done()` callback

Comment: yep, thanks.  that did it.  it's not pretty but I tucked that line in the last .get and works as intended.

Comment: There is no guarantee that will work - the last `$.get()` may be completed before the previous ones

Comment: hehe, I was about to say "before you say anything, ....etc..etc....."   what you said :)  ugly bit of code though, should probably move all that into a single call...thanks for the assist

Comment: Sounds like a good plan to me :)

Comment: All those jquery gets effectively return promises - you should be able to store the return value from the three `$.get` calls and pass them in to `$.when` to get a new promise that you can add `.done()` onto, that won't actually happen until all three are done.